# Transposing a matrix results in wrong output

Tags: c++, matrix, visual-studio-2013, transpose

I am trying to transpose a 4 by 5 matrix to a 5 by 4 matrix. This is what I have done so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void transposeMatrix(int A2[4][5],int A1[5][4])
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            A1[j][i]=A2[i][j];
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int A2[4][5] = {
        { 7, 4, 2, 1, 12 },
        { 4, 6, 22, 11, 6 },
        { 12, 10, 3, 1, 2 },
        { 20, 4, 1, 3, 4 },
    };
    int A1[5][4];
    int i, j;

    printf("Original matrix:\n ");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        for (j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            printf("%5i", A2[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Transposed matrix:\n");
    transposeMatrix(A2, A1);
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            printf("%5i", A1[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run my code, this is what I get:

```
Original matrix:
     7    4    2    1   12
    4    6   22   11    6
   12   10    3    1    2
   20    4    1    3    4
Transposed matrix:
    7    4   12   20
-858993460    6   10    4
998952744   22    3    1
11599080   11    1    3
10495049-858993460-858993460-858993460
```

It looks like it only transposes the first row. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: The `return 0;` in the main function is inside the for loop. So you just print the first line and then exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one error in your code.

It is an index problem in the `transpose` function.

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
        A1[i][j]=A2[j][i];
}
```

and not `A1[j][i]=A2[i][j]`.

Comment: Thank you so much. You fixed my problem.

Comment: @Frank return is correct, it's outside for loop's block

Comment: @Raindrop ok, thanks I remove it from my post. When I copy-pasted the code, it was inside.